# How to upgrade node without breaking all dependencies?

Tags: node.js

I have a project in Vue 2, that is still using node 12. I need to install a new lib that only works with node 14+. Therefore I'm trying to upgrade node to the next version that works with my project, ideally node 18, but if that doesn't work, I'll use node 16 or 14.

The problem is that when I upgrade node, a bunch of my dependencies turn out incompatible, so I have to find the best suited version for each one. And each new version of a dependency breaks it's own dependencies. That seems like a pretty hard puzzle.

Is there any better way to do this? Hopefuly an automated way?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I researched a lot but didn't get any solution so far.